# Building NITRO NITF library on Windows using Waf

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, build, waf

I'm trying to build the NITRO NITF library on Windows 64 bit. Also, I need to build the C++ shared libraries to link against, i.e., DLLs not just EXEs.

I'm trying to build with:

```
python waf configure build --enable-debugging --prefix=installed --enable-cpp11 --enable-64bit --dist-source --msvc_targets=x64 --shared
```

but during the build I'm getting: `invalid def file 'lib/libxerces.def'`

The library is located here: https://github.com/mdaus/nitro

Does anyone have experience building this library on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in NITRO that was just somewhat fixed. It's not all the way there, but now to get going you can do

```
python waf configure --enable-debugging --prefix=installed --enable-cpp11 --enable-64bit --dist-source --msvc_targets=x64 install
python waf configure --enable-debugging --prefix=installed --enable-cpp11 --enable-64bit --dist-source --msvc_targets=x64 --shared install
```

(Yes, both commands are required.)

That will get you DLLs for just the C layer of NITRO.

If you have future issues with NITRO, a faster way to get help would be to open an issue on the GitHub page.